# To extract tar only if there's not been the same file/directory

Tags: filesystems, tar

how to extract by use of tar only if there's not been the same file/directory exist, skip it otherwise ?
e.g. illustration

```
tar xf foo  # ...?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -k option to keep old files (will give a warning)

```
tar -x -k -f files.tar
```

Or use the `--skip-old-files' option to silently ignore existing files

```
tar -x --skip-old-files -f files.tar
```